# PS script pauses after first line completes (pressing enter makes it continue)

Tags: powershell

I have had assistance on the script below and each line worked when ran separately. But when I try to run them together the "RemoveADGroupMember" line works and pauses at the "Get-ADComputer" line. If I hit enter then the "Get-AdComputer" line completes fine. I have found many ways to pause a script but nothing to make it not pause. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Remove-ADGroupMember "wk_test" -Members (Get-ADGroupMember "wk_test") -Confirm:$false 
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "CN=computers,DC=ad,dc=local" -Filter * | foreach {Add-ADGroupMember "wk_test" -Members $_.DistinguishedName}
```

Comment: Try using this as your second line - I think your original code was better (no need for the pipe)     `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "wk_test" -Members (Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "CN=computers,DC=ad,dc=org" -filter *) `

Comment: Itchydon, I just tried it and it still pauses until I het enter. This is insane, I can't tell you how many different types of search terms I have used to try and find out why this is happening. Thanks for trying

Comment: when it pause what is the exact message?

Comment: also what is the output if you enter     `$ErrorActionPreference`

Comment: It shows  a blinking cursor at the end of the Add-ADGroupMember line. Do I add $ErrorActionPreference at the end of the last line or at the beginning. Obviously I am a noob at this.

Comment: I just meant in the same console that you are running the script - type that at the prompt and hit enter.  No need to add it to the script

Comment: Ok try putting a     `-confirm:false` after the     `add-adgroupmember`.  Like this    `Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "CN=computers,DC=ad,dc=local" -Filter * | foreach {Add-ADGroupMember "wk_test" -Members $_.DistinguishedName -confirm:false}`

Comment: This is the response I get back

Comment: I entered the $ErrorActionPreference in the PS window and  got Continue This is the response I get when running the script                      Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot convert 'System.String' to the type
'System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter' required by parameter 'Confirm'. At line:1 char:150+ ... edName-confirm:false}
+ CategoryInfo  : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory. Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why it is prompting you - I have slightly re-written the code using the `foreach` statement instead of `foreach-object`.  Does this still prompt you?

```
Remove-ADGroupMember "wk_test" -Members (Get-ADGroupMember "wk_test") -Confirm:$false 
$comps = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "CN=computers,DC=ad,dc=local" -Filter *
foreach ($comp in $comps) {
    Add-ADGroupMember "wk_test" -Members $comp
}
```

Comment: That did the same thing. But in desperation I added get-Host to the next line and then the script finished. I am really scratching my head on this one. It makes no sense. Thanks for all your help Itchydon

Comment: No worries buddy - shame we didn't quite crack it though!  It is something peculiar to your system as all of your codes have worked my end without a problem  :-)